neat beans build failed error How to fixed that issue?
This is shown in the output window when I run a very simple code made by my neatbeans software. how to fix this error. what is the reason.
cd C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject3; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-22" cmd /c "\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-21\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dexec.vmArgs= \"-Dexec.args=${exec.vmArgs} -classpath %classpath ${exec.mainClass} ${exec.appArgs}\" -Dexec.appArgs= -Dexec.mainClass=com.mycompany.mavenproject3.Mavenproject3 \"-Dexec.executable=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-22\\bin\\java.exe\" \"-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-21\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" --no-transfer-progress process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec"
Scanning for projects...

--------------------< com.mycompany:mavenproject3 >---------------------
Building mavenproject3 1.0-SNAPSHOT
  from pom.xml
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ mavenproject3 ---
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject3\src\main\resources

--- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ mavenproject3 ---
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  0.933 s
Finished at: 2024-05-05T17:20:36+05:30
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project mavenproject3: Error while storing the mojo status: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject3\target\maven-status\maven-compiler-plugin\compile\default-compile\inputFiles.lst -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Since I am newbie, I have no idea about this. I search the internet but could not find a proper answer.

This is often a permission issue. Did you rerun the command with the debug flags to have more details?
